some issues when i using easy_handeye to calibrate
I was looking for some advice from someone who was able to get  package of easy_handey working with ROS Noetic, my virtual environment python version is 2.7.18.
The main issue I'm having is indirectly related to this package and has to do with PyQt5. When I run
roslaunch easy_handeye ur5e_d435i_eyeonhand_calibration.launch

I can't get the GUI of rqt, like below

I only can see two rviz

Meahwhile, I got some errors
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/cpp_binding_helper.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import libqt_gui_cpp_sip
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name


I think the problem is caused by vesion of pyqt5. However, I try to choose different version of pyqt5, the problem is still exist and it is same.
it almost take me a week to find how to solve this problem,but i didn't solve.
Does someone konw how to fix it ? I would be very appreciated!!
